# Необходимо модифицировать код так, чтобы при выводе имени файла не отображалось расширение (.doc .pdf и т.п.)

Tags: php

Необходимо модифицировать код так, чтобы при выводе ИМЕНИ файла не отображалось расширение (.doc .pdf и т.п.)

```
<?php 

$dir="/directory_documents/"; 
$ar=array(); 
$dh = opendir($dir); 
while ($file_d = readdir($dh)) : 
if ($file_d[0] != ".") 
{ 
  array_push($ar, $file_d); 
} 
endwhile; 
closedir($dh);

sort($ar); 

for($i=0;$i<count($ar);$i++) { 
  print "<a href='".$dir.$ar[$i]."' target='_blank'> $ar[$i] </a> "; 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на функцию [basename](http://www.php.su/basename)

```
<?php 

$dir="/directory_documents/"; 
$ar=array(); 
$dh = opendir($dir); 
while ($file_d = readdir($dh)) : 
if ($file_d[0] != ".") 
{ 
  array_push($ar, $file_d); 
} 
endwhile; 
closedir($dh);

sort($ar); 

for($i=0;$i<count($ar);$i++) { 
  print "<a href='".$dir.$ar[$i]."' target='_blank'>".basename($ar[$i])."</a>"; 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно посмотреть в сторону функции [pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php), которая возвращает информацию о пути к файлу:

```
<?php 

$dir="/directory_documents/"; 
$ar=array(); 
$dh = opendir($dir); 
while ($file_d = readdir($dh)) : 
if ($file_d[0] != ".") 
{ 
  array_push($ar, $file_d); 
} 
endwhile; 
closedir($dh);

sort($ar); 

for($i=0;$i<count($ar);$i++) { 
  print "<a href='".$dir.$ar[$i]."' target='_blank'>".pathinfo ( $dir.$ar[$i], PATHINFO_FILENAME ] ) </a> "; 
}

?>
```